# Extract value from class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get value "Anti-Mage" from class in python. How can I do it?

```
<td class="cell-xlarge"><a href="/players/432283612/matches?hero=anti-mage">Anti-Mage</a><div class="subtext minor"><a href="/matches/6107031786"><time data-time-ago="2021-07-26T23:27:54+00:00" datetime="2021-07-26T23:27:54+00:00" title="Mon, 26 Jul 2021 23:27:54 +0000">2021-07-26</time></a></div></td>
```

Comment: Question should be improved to get more specific answers. Take a minute to read ->  How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to select the parent item (`td` in this case) from its class name. You can do something like

```py
td = soup.find('td', {'class': 'cell-xlarge'})
```

and then find the `a` children tags with something like this

```py
a = td.findChildren('a', recursive=False)[0]
```

And this will give you the `a` tag. To get its value, you use `.string` like this

```py
a_value = a.string
```

And that gives you the value of **Anti-Mage**

Comment: Thats works! But how to make cycle "for" to find all items from class?

Like:

Anti-Mage,
Shadow Fiend,
Slark,
.....

Comment: Like all `a` tags in a certain div? See the [0] I wrote in the 2nd code block, that is accessing the first `a` in the list of `a`'s that are children of the `td` with class `cell-xlarge`. Don't write the [0] and then loop over the list to get the `.string` of every `a` tag

Comment: hm, I add my answering in question check. This is not right code but whay I should change?

Comment: no idea mate, but i don't think posting code like this is very good. let's talk in some DMs if this problem is complex

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Based on your comment, to get all the `<a>`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.dotabuff.com/players/432283612'
headers = {
    "Accept":"*/*",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

[x.text for x in soup.select('article a[href*="matches?hero"]')]
```

#### Output

```
['Anti-Mage', 'Shadow Fiend', 'Slark', 'Morphling', 'Tinker', 'Bristleback', 'Invoker', 'Broodmother', 'Templar Assassin', 'Monkey King']
```

---

Assuming HTML posted in your question is the `BeautifulSoup` object, call `text` method on the `<a>`:

```
soup.a.text
```

or select more specific with class you mentioned:

```
soup.select_one('.cell-xlarge a').text
```

**Note:** *Selecting elements by `class` in some cases is only third best option, cause classes can be dynamic, are not unique, ... - Better  strategies are to select by id, tag*

Answer (score 1):

```
r1 = requests.get(f"https://www.dotabuff.com/players/{a}/heroes", headers = headers)

html1 = BS(r1.content, 'lxml')


for a in html1.find('td', {'class': 'cell-xlarge'}):
    b = a.findChildren('a', recursive=False)
    a_value = b.string



    print(a_value)
```